# why ul li's float left properity is not appiled on first child of li

Tags: html, css

ul li defined as float left,so the main li's are came side by side,but how first li's childs are coming one after other,but it seems ul li properties applying on first li's child too..can some explain me

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
ul {

margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none;

}
ul li {
list-style:none;
float :left;
width:150px;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
background-color:yellow;

}

ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul><li>Honda</li>
            <li>Maruthi</li>
            <li>Suzuki</li>
            <li>Kawaski</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ContactUs</a>
        <ul><li>Honda</li>
            <li>Maruthi</li>
            <li>Suzuki</li>
            <li>Kawaski</li>
        </ul>

        </li>
    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FeedBack</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using descendant selectors, which means ANY li in your document will be styled that way.

If you only want to target the first ul and those first li's use a class for the ul and the child selector, like this:

```
.first > li { }
```

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/19xxvhpt/